# How to run an application within a Mac application with Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, process

So I'm designing a system that required an application of a known name and path on the system to be run on demand. The application to run will be a text-based application, which can be easily ran by calling `system("./xxx")`

But here's my concern, is there a better way to do it with Objective-C? For example, to get additional information about the process after it has ran, and possibly terminate it or time it?

What class and thoughts could I use that would be better than just calling that system function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Though, if you need to do any IPC, I would suggest an [XPC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html) service.

---

If you want to time the task, do something like:

```
 NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];

 ... run the task ...

 NSDate *endDate = [NSDate date];
```

Then you can do a bit of date math (using the methods on NSDate) to figure out elapsed time.  Actually, doing this with `NSTimeInterval`s is easier;  they are just floating point numbers representing # of seconds since epoch, subtract the former from the latter and you have elapsed time.

Of course, if you are running the task in the background, you'll need to start the dates / time intervals in ivars or something.

Comment: Yes, I've heard of XPC service, and seen a few session videos. But being mainly on iOS, never really used that. Thanks!!

Comment: Is there anyway to time the task? I don't see any property/method about that.